# Read version info from .ABR file (Photoshop brush set)

Tags: python, binary, hex, photoshop

Is it possible to detect which Photoshop version a brush set (.abr) file is compatible with from its binary data?

There is a open source C# programm called [ABRViewer](http://abrviewer.sourceforge.net/) but it doesn't read version info.

Sample brushes:

http://mark-s.deviantart.com/art/Fractal-Brushes-Set-20484978

http://redheadstock.deviantart.com/art/Arcane-Circles-Symbols-Brushes-63580135

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are on Windows, you may have some luck using Python's [win32com](http://python.net/crew/skippy/win32/Downloads.html) to interact with Photoshop programatically (a [nice example](http://techarttiki.blogspot.com/2008/08/photoshop-scripting-with-python.html)).  Perhaps you could try to load in an ABR file via this API.

Based upon [this forum post](http://forums.adobe.com/thread/359993), it appears that there is a document "Photoshop File Formats," which is included in the Advanced SDK.  Apparently you can get the [Advanced SDK for free](http://blogs.adobe.com/jnack/2006/03/sdk_no_pay.html). I would assume this document would expain the ABR file format so that you could write a simple parser.